# Module not found for React Ntaive Webrtc while creating Android build

Tags: javascript, react-native, webrtc

I added Webrtc https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-webrtc module in my react-native-web app.

I used `npm i -s react-native-webrtc` command. But while creating a build I am getting below error:

> Error: Error: Unable to resolve module `react-native-webrtc` from
>   `App.js`: react-native-webrtc could not be found within the project or
>   in these directories:   node_modules
>
> If you are sure the module exists, try these steps:
>    1. Clear watchman watches: watchman watch-del-all
>    2. Delete node_modules: rm -rf node_modules and run yarn install
>    3. Reset Metro's cache: yarn start --reset-cache
>    4. Remove the cache: rm -rf /tmp/metro-*
>       at ModuleResolver.resolveDependency (D:\smartek_project\video_conferencing\newchanges\VC_Frontend\node_modules\metro\src\node-haste\DependencyGraph\ModuleResolution.js:186:15)
>       at ResolutionRequest.resolveDependency (D:\smartek_project\video_conferencing\newchanges\VC_Frontend\node_modules\metro\src\node-haste\DependencyGraph\ResolutionRequest.js:52:18)
>       at DependencyGraph.resolveDependency (D:\smartek_project\video_conferencing\newchanges\VC_Frontend\node_modules\metro\src\node-haste\DependencyGraph.js:287:16)
>       at Object.resolve (D:\smartek_project\video_conferencing\newchanges\VC_Frontend\node_modules\metro\src\lib\transformHelpers.js:267:42)
>       at dependencies.map.result (D:\smartek_project\video_conferencing\newchanges\VC_Frontend\node_modules\metro\src\DeltaBundler\traverseDependencies.js:434:31)
>       at Array.map ()
>       at resolveDependencies (D:\smartek_project\video_conferencing\newchanges\VC_Frontend\node_modules\metro\src\DeltaBundler\traverseDependencies.js:431:18)
>       at D:\smartek_project\video_conferencing\newchanges\VC_Frontend\node_modules\metro\src\DeltaBundler\traverseDependencies.js:275:33
>       at Generator.next ()
>       at asyncGeneratorStep (D:\smartek_project\video_conferencing\newchanges\VC_Frontend\node_modules\metro\src\DeltaBundler\traverseDependencies.js:87:24)

Here is my package.json dependenci

```
"dependencies": {
    "@babel/polyfill": "^7.10.1",
    "@react-native-community/masked-view": "^0.1.10",
    "@react-native-community/voice": "^1.1.4",
    "@react-navigation/bottom-tabs": "^5.5.1",
    "@react-navigation/native": "^5.5.0",
    "@react-navigation/stack": "^5.4.1",
    "babel-plugin-react-native-web": "^0.12.2",
    "core-js": "^3.6.5",
    "react": "16.11.0",
    "react-dom": "^16.13.1",
    "react-native": "^0.62.2",
    "react-native-gesture-handler": "^1.6.1",
    "react-native-reanimated": "^1.9.0",
    "react-native-safe-area-context": "^3.0.2",
    "react-native-screens": "^2.8.0",
    "react-native-web": "^0.12.2",
    "react-native-webrtc": "^1.75.3"
  },
```

Comment: Can you provide `distributionUrl` from `android/gradle/wrapper/gradle-wrapper.properties` this path and `classpath` from `android/build.gradle` this path? I am using this version of `react-native-webrtc` with `react-native v62.2`.

Comment: @ShahnawazHossan 

distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-6.0.1-all.zip

com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.5.2

Comment: Please follow the instructions I have answered below. Let me know whether everything is working or not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I struggled a lot of days with this issue. Simply follow the instructions I have figured out. (I am using `react-native-cli`)

**`Step 1:`**

```sh
$ rm -rf node_modules/
$ npm i
$ npm i react-native-webrtc --save
```

**`Step 2:`**
Replace `distributionUrl` by this URL `https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-5.5.1-all.zip`

**`Step 3:`**
Replace your `classpath` by this `classpath("com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.4.1")` from `android/build.gradle` this file.

**`Step 4:`**

```sh
$ cd android
$ ./gradlew clean
$ cd ..
$ react-native run-android
```

Hopefully, this will work.

Comment: this wont affect my future android builds?

Comment: Try creating a new project and follow the steps. I have checked it up right now. Also, are you using `react-native-cli` ?

Comment: I will recommend you to create a new app and try this. This has worked for me.

Comment: And this won't affect your future android builds. If it goes well on your current app then ok and if not then create a new app and try these steps.

Comment: It is working for new react-native app but in my existing app it is not working

Answer (score 1):

There were two issues due to which I was getting error.

1. The `metro.config.js` had below line

   ```
    resolver: {
               blacklistRE: /react-native-web/,
               sourceExts: ["js", "json", "ts", "tsx", "android.js", "ios.js"]
             }
   ```

due to "**blacklistRE**" the webrtc module was not include while running the app on android.That is why I was getting **module not found error**. I solve it by changing into below lines of code

```
     resolver: {
    blacklistRE: /\react-native-web\b/,
    sourceExts: ["js", "json", "ts", "tsx", "android.js", "ios.js"]
  }
```

2. After solving this build was getting created but app  was not launcing for this I used above suggested changes for android by @Shahnawaz Hossan. And I also updated `AndroidManifest.xml` in `android\app\src\main` with below lines:

   ```
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
     <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" />
     <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera.autofocus"/>
     <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
   ```

```
   <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO" />
   <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
   <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
```